# Using gui (nautilus, say) to copy root files while preserving permissions

Tags: nautilus, permissions, root

Using a gui, I would like to copy a folder hierarchy in which some files belong to a user, some to root, producing an exact copy (same file permissions in target).

Using

```
gksudo nautilus
```

allows to copy root-owned files, but changes permissions to root root (at least when test running it on my system, 12.04.). How can the above be done?